# Let $x_1+x_2,...+x_{12}=12$. What are all the Integer solutions of $x_1,x_2,...,x_{12}$($\geq 0$)?

Tags: combinatorics

I being trying to solve this, and I know there exists a formula but I can't recall it.

What I tried was a lower scenario, i.e, when there is only $x_1, x_2, x_3$. 
I took the idea of supposing that $x_1=0$. Then, there are 13 possible solutions for $x_2, x_3$. Then when $x_1=1$ there are 12 possibilities, and so on. Then there exist $1+2+...+13=91$ possibilities fixing $x_1$. Similarly, fixing $x_2, x_3$ we get 91+91 possibilities. So the total possibilities is 273.

But how would I generalize this for when I have 12 x's?

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: What you mean to ask is how many nonnegative integers solutions to the equation are there?

Comment: It is possible that "integer programming" could offer an answer, where you would have a dummy objective function and the equation as a constraint assuming all variables are >0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of non-negative integer solutions to the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n\\x_i\geq 0\end{cases}$$

will be

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

This is seen by using a standard [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) style argument by comparing this situation to the one where we arrange a collection of $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars in a row and interpreting the number of stars in each group separated by the bars as the value of $x_i$.

Comment: On the wikipedia page you sent, it was (n+1,k-1) though...

Comment: @pratik there are many similar questions, the one asking how many *positive* integer solutions there are rather than just non-negative, the one where there are n variables instead of k, the one where the variables add up to k instead of n, etc... The version of the problem as written has the answer I write above and the most common explanation for why is as mentioned using the concept of stars and bars.